# Customshapes in Limejs

Tags: html, limejs

I want to know the custom shape creation in html5 using LimeJS.Could anyone tell me how to create a custom shape like comment in a game using LimeJS for html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for images

```
 var gameMap = new lime.Sprite().setSize(400,300).setFill('images/bk.jpg').setPosition(0,0).setAnchorPoint(0,0);
```

for custom shapes we have to fill with different points

Answer (score 0):

You essentially create a custom sprite, and render the UI appropriately, which could be a combination of elements.  The shell needs to be:

```
test.board = function() {
    goog.base(this);

}
goog.inherits(test.board, lime.Sprite);
```

Text input isn't direct; here is an article on text input: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/limejs/txaxgK3eXQg.  You can use a label, and attach to the key press event.  I don't know if this works for canvas rendering...